# Code modifying to identify category in html code

Tags: javascript, html, if-statement, categories

I need to modify the code below to be able to identify which category the user is in. The categories are:

- Less than 18.5    Underweight
- 18.5 to 25    Normal
- 25-30         Overweight
- More than 30  Obese

Then at the end I need the code to automatically know what category the user is in and display: this means you are (Underweight,normal etc)

thank you.

```
<html>
<head>
    <title>BMI Calculator</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function computeBMI()
        {
            //Obtain user inputs
            var height=Number(document.getElementById("height").value);
            varheightunits=document.getElementById("heightunits").value;
            var weight=Number(document.getElementById("weight").value);
            varweightunits=document.getElementById("weightunits").value;

            //Convert all units to metric
            if (heightunits=="inches") height/=39.3700787;
            if (weightunits=="lb") weight/=2.20462;

            //Perform calculation
            var BMI=weight/Math.pow(height,2);

            //Display result of calculation
            document.getElementById("output").innerText=Math.round(BMI*100)/100;
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Body Mass Index Calculator</h1>
    <p>Enter your height: <input type="text" id="height"/>
        <select type="multiple" id="heightunits">
            <option value="metres" selected="selected">metres</option>
            <option value="inches">inches</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <p>Enter your weight: <input type="text" id="weight"/>
        <select type="multiple" id="weightunits">
            <option value="kg" selected="selected">kilograms</option>
            <option value="lb">pounds</option>
        </select>
    </p>
    <input type="submit" value="computeBMI" onclick="computeBMI();">
    <h1>Your BMI is: <span id="output">?</span></h1>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Why do I feel like I'm doing someone's school assignment?

Comment: Haha, well, you are :P

Comment: Well, there are some syntax errors... `varheightunits` is probably `var heightunits`

Answer (score 0):

Add this line in your HTML, maybe below the `<h1>` tag:

```
<span id="id_here"></span>
```

Any other element will work though as long as it has an id.

Then in your JS, you add this:

```
var writeThere = document.getElementById("id_of_the_element_below_h1");

if(ans < 18.5) {
   writeThere.innerText= "You are underweight";
} else if(ans > 18.5 && ans < 25) { 
   writeThere.innerText= "You are normal";
} else if(ans > 25 && ans < 30) { 
   writeThere.innerText= "You are overweight";
} else {
   writeThere.innerText= "You are obese";
}
```

You might ask where's variable **ans**, it can be right here:

```
var ans = Math.round(BMI*100)/100;
//Display result of calculation
 document.getElementById("output").innerText= ans;
```

Comment: You need to change your code because if someone was exactly 18.5 or 25 they would be obese. You could remove the greater than part of each test as these are redundant because the 'if/else if' will capture a lower value. For example else if(ans < 25). This would then fix the issue.

Comment: I know that full well, but that's what the questioner wants, so I'll let it slide.